# Get variable in svn-external

Tags: svn, global-variables, svn-externals

I'm wondering if it is possible to get a (global) variable in an svn-external property, or one at any place.
When looking answer for my question, I found not that much about variables...
I'd like to do something like:

```
svn:externals subproject <svn.base.url>/project/subproject/trunk
```

What are the different possibilities to define the '`svn.base.url`' variable?

Or is it better to do it hardcoded and then change it with `propget --recursive`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there's no way to interpolate variables within an property value, however if you want this so that you can create relative `svn:externals`, then you may be able to use the [relative externals syntax](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html).  (Needs subversion 1.5+.)